# Flex convert xmllistcollection object into xml

Tags: java, apache-flex, adobe, flash-builder

I have my existing flex project that use flex XML object to populate UI components that XML object I was creating from response received from a URLLoader. But in a new requirement I am not using URLLoader and my proxy layer returning XMLListCollection object from back end. Is there any way to convert flex XMLListCollection object into flex XML object?

Answer (score 1):

You can get XMLList from `source` porperty.